# How do I include a package after installing it with NuGet?

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'm trying to play with FSharp.Data and I installed it with this command:

```
 mono nuget.exe install FSharp.Data -Version 1.1.10
```

It put a folder called FSharp.Data.1.1.10 in that directory, so I guess it worked.  Now I'd like to actual *use* FSharp.Data but I can't figure out how to include it.

So far all I have is:

```
 open FSharp.Data
```

and I'm trying to compile like this:

```
 fsharpc -I /home/frew/code/fsharp/FSharp.Data.1.1.10 test.fs
```

I've also tried appending lib, lib/net40, and lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll to the path above, all to no avail.

What do I do?

(I'm on ubuntu and installed mono 3.2 from a ppm)

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: updated info for that

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you need to include both the directory and the name of the dll with separate options.  So this is what worked for me:

```
 fsharpc -r FSharp.Data  -I /home/frew/code/fsharp/FSharp.Data.1.1.10/lib/net40 test.fs
```

Comment: Compiling like that worked for me, but running... not so much. Do I also need to pass those ooptions to mono?